# JavaFX 2.0 Table with multiline table header

Tags: javafx-2

Is it possible to make javaFX 2.0 table with multiline header?
All the examples, which i have found on the web, have tables, where columnt header width = its text size, without wraping.  The exaple of what i have, and what i need is shown on a screen:[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came up with the following function:

```
private void makeHeaderWrappable(TableColumn col) {
  Label label = new Label(col.getText());
  label.setStyle("-fx-padding: 8px;");
  label.setWrapText(true);
  label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

  StackPane stack = new StackPane();
  stack.getChildren().add(label);
  stack.prefWidthProperty().bind(col.widthProperty().subtract(5));
  label.prefWidthProperty().bind(stack.prefWidthProperty());
  col.setGraphic(stack);
}
```

A complete executable example is [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/2898196) (requires the [2.2 developer preview as a minimum](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWrappedHeaders extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name (which is a really long name)");
    makeHeaderWrappable(firstNameCol);
    firstNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("lastName"));

    TableView table = new TableView();
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
      new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
      new Person("Ethan", "Williams")
    ));
    table.setPrefSize(250, 200);

    Pane layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;");
    layout.getChildren().addAll(table);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }

  private void makeHeaderWrappable(TableColumn col) {
    Label label = new Label(col.getText());
    label.setStyle("-fx-padding: 8px;");
    label.setWrapText(true);
    label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.getChildren().add(label);
    stack.prefWidthProperty().bind(col.widthProperty().subtract(5));
    label.prefWidthProperty().bind(stack.prefWidthProperty());
    col.setText(null);
    col.setGraphic(stack);
  }

  public static class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

    private Person(String fName, String lName) {
      this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
      this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
    public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName.set(fName); }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
    public void setLastName(String fName) { lastName.set(fName); }
  }
}
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but the function above did at least work for me in my test case.

I thought this would be achievable with a simple css style, but I could not get it to work via css alone.

Comment: First, jewelsea... I always cherish your answers.  I am noticing some odd behavior in Java 8 with this solution.  Initially everything looks fine, but if I double click the column header dividers (which typically resizes the column to fit to the contents) it keeps increasing the column's width.  It never gets smaller, only bigger.  Any suggestions or ideas as to why that might be happening?

Comment: The gist does not compile.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine for me on JavaFX 9.0.4, still suffers the issue pointed out by Tommo.

Comment: I inlined the gist so it isn't stored on another site and added a col.setText(null) call which fixes some of the resizing issue pointed out by Tommo (to the point where the behaviour, at least for the test case here, seemed acceptable to me).  In general, in my opinion, using binding for layout like is done here is usually not the ideal solution, but I don't have a better solution for the time being.

Answer (score 16):

Found a solution without using labels. In Scene Builder 8.3.0 (Gluon) , JavaFX 8 , a button appears on mouse hover, just right of the Text field, where a multi - line can be chosen from the menu.

[image: Menu for multi - line mode]

This results in a following XML code:

```
<TableColumn fx:id="prodDisc" editable="false" prefWidth="50.0" text="Prod &#10;Disc" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Is easier with a Label in the header graphic of the column:

1. Add a label in the column header graphic (if the column has some text as title delete it).
2. Set the label to allow Wrap Text 
   (Scene Builder -> go to Properties of the label and select Wrap Text or in Code -> label.setWrapText(true))
3. Set label width and height we wish

Note: is easier to do this in a FXML (with Scene Builder) than in code.

Example below:

```
    public class TableColumnLongTextLabel extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView table = new TableView();
        TableColumn tableColumnData1 = new TableColumn(),
                tableColumnData2 = new TableColumn("Long Title without Text Wrap");

        tableColumnData1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SomeStructure, String>("data1"));
        tableColumnData2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SomeStructure, String>("data2"));

        table.getColumns().addAll(tableColumnData1, tableColumnData2);

        Label columnTitle = new Label("Long Title with Text Wrapped");
        columnTitle.setPrefWidth(125);
        columnTitle.setPrefHeight(50);
        columnTitle.setWrapText(true);
        columnTitle.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        tableColumnData1.setGraphic(columnTitle);

        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new SomeStructure("Java", "FX", 1),
                new SomeStructure("Java", "Swing", 0),
                new SomeStructure("Java", "Sample", 2),
                new SomeStructure("Some", "Other", 10)
        ));

        Pane layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(table);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 350, 350));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class SomeStructure {

        private final SimpleStringProperty data1;
        private final SimpleStringProperty data2;
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty data3;

        private SomeStructure(String data1, String data2, Integer data3) {
            this.data1 = new SimpleStringProperty(data1);
            this.data2 = new SimpleStringProperty(data2);
            this.data3 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(data3);
        }

        public String getData1() {
            return data1.get();
        }

        public void setData1(String data1) {
            this.data1.set(data1);
        }

        public String getData2() {
            return data2.get();
        }

        public void setData2(String data2) {
            this.data2.set(data2);
        }

        public Integer getData3() {
            return data3.get();
        }

        public void setData3(Integer data3) {
            this.data3.set(data3);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Example using FXML (No code needed :) ):

```
<TableView prefHeight="251.0" prefWidth="556.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
       <columns>
          <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="90.0" prefWidth="70.0" sortable="false" text="Player">
             <columns>
                <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="80.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="ID" />
                <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="200.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Name" />
             </columns>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn maxWidth="80.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Game" />
          <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="160.0" minWidth="125.0" prefWidth="135.0" sortable="false" text="Team" visible="false" />
          <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="160.0" minWidth="107.0" prefWidth="107.0" sortable="false">
             <graphic>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" text="Individual Points (Big Team)" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
             </graphic>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="160.0" minWidth="99.0" prefWidth="102.0" sortable="false">
             <graphic>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" text="Team Points (Small Maps)" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
             </graphic>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="116.0" minWidth="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" sortable="false">
             <graphic>
                <Label text="Total Points" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
             </graphic>
          </TableColumn>
       </columns>
    </TableView>
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can include the code that resulted in the Player column with ID and Name beneath?

Comment: You mean how to add those two columns below one master column?
if yes the code is simple: 

`tableColumnPlayer.getColumns().add(tableColumnID);
tableColumnPlayer.getColumns().add(tableColumnName);`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to align header text is with CSS style, like this:

```
.table-view .column-header .label {
  -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Use new line escape sequence "\n" in header text string to split it into multiple lines.