# Can I gain granular control of how a row is rendered in JAVA?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am building a table in JAVA but some rows need to be completely different than most based on options.

In PHP I could loop a data set and apply an IF statement and change how a row is renedred in a webpage

```
while($r = $sth->fetch()){
    if ($r['status']=='good'){
        echo '<tr><td>This is good</td><td>yes it is</td></tr>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">this is bad</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

I only know one way to render a table in JAVA:

```
TableView<StatuTable> table = new TableView();

TableColumn<StatuTable, String> statusColumn = new TableColumn<>("Status");
statusColumn .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));

TableColumn<StatuTable, String> noteColumn = new TableColumn<>("Note");
noteColumn .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("note"));

//loop the statusGroup defined elsewhere
    ObservableList<StatusTable> statusList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (Status status: statusGroup.getStatusRows()){
        Can I alter the table row here:
        if (status.getStatusType.equals("good")){
             //make a different kind of row.
        }
        statusList.add(status);
    }

    table .setItems(statusList);

    //this part is black magic as far as i am concerned
    scheduleTable.getColumns().addAll(statusColumn, noteColumn);
```

Comment: Start by having a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html), look for the section titled *"Customizing TableView Visuals"*.  Then maybe something like [JavaFX 8 TableView Cell Renderer](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/) could help

Comment: yep, i have read through the tableView cell render-er but I am not sure if I can make a cell span columns. although it does make it click that in the customCellFactory I can query the item for it's value right.

Comment: You can make headers span columns, but there is no straightforward way to make a cell span multiple columns.  It might be theoretically possible, but any solution is likely to be elaborate and rely on behaviors which are not guaranteed.

Comment: I get that. So would there be a better way to present the data? Is there a different view I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing off of the example in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864130/866021), you can do this via the `getStyleClass()` function on your `TableRow`.

Add an appropriate style class to your row:

```
nameRow.getStyleClass().add("italic");
```

Add a stylesheet to your scene which defines the italic style for table cells:

```
.italic.table-cell { -fx-font-style: italic; }
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer for some help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33970786/866021

Comment: ok, thats a step in the right direction.. I can see that I can nest with: nameColumn.getColumns().addAll(firstNameColumn, lastNameColumn); So would i then do a custom cell factory and find out if I need to nest or not?

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend starting there.